# SharePoint Sandbox Solution Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, sandbox-solution, web-template, module

I have developed web template in visual studio sandbox solution.

Sandbox solution is worked fine in on premises but when i am going to activate WSP and create new sub site using this web template i m facing below error.

Sandbox solution includes following stuff:

1) Site columns(Feature activated at site collection level manually)

2) Site content types(Feature activated at site collection level manually)

3) List definition(Feature activated at site collection level manually)

4) List instances(Feature activated from ONET.XML File)

5) module (Feature activated at site collection level manually)

6)Page Provision (Feature activated from ONEt.XML File)

7) Web Template Property Bag(Feature activated from ONET.XMl File)

**ERROR:**

**"Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred."**

Comment: When moving from on premise to sandboxed solution, did you check your solution´s content for things, not allowed in Sandboxed solution? Eg, in Sandboxed solutions mapped Folders are not possible, this seems a possible reason for your error when you mention onet.xml files

Comment: @LeopoldLerch  No I have not Use any Mapped folder in the solution. I have use only those things which is supported by sandbox solution . Can i user Spclass in sandbox solution ?  because  i have used it in event receiver to Set lookup column  value.